# Is possible to spoof user-agent and OS with Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, user-agent, spoof

What are the options to block the methods bellow with Chrome?

`navigator.appVersion`

`Info os.name`

as I was successfully profiled in

http://browserspy.dk/browser.php

I´d like to hide Browser and OS in order to avoid exploits.

Comment: You can use chromes emulation console to spoof user agent

Answer (score 20):

You can change the User Agent string in Dev Tools:

1. Open **Developer Tools** (<kbd>F12</kbd>)
   [image: Developer Tools]
2. Show the **Console Drawer** at the bottom by hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>
   [image: Console Drawer]
3. Add the **Network Conditions** tab to the drawer
   [image: Network Conditions]
4. Under **User Agent**, uncheck "Select automatically", and pick a browser you wish to emulate or customize the string however you'd like
   [image: User Agent]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the User-Agent string Chrome sends to the servers. [This is explained here](http://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-change-user-agent-string).